# how to set django and mysql work with UTF-8

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8

I want to set my Django/mysql site to work with UTF-8. Please guide me the changes I have to make in django and mysql to make sure the following things.

1. User entered data in the forms will be always encoded as UTF-8
2. Storing the data in mysql as utf-8
3. Displaying utf8 encoded data in the template correctly
4. Also I want to know whether moving to UTF-8 encoding will remove unicode decode error like below.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

here some advices:

1) use utf8 encoding when creating database

```
CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#creating-your-database)

2) place the following special comment in the first or second lines of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

[nice article about python and utf8](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html)

3) Use unicode strings with u prefix in *.py files

```
unicodeString = u"hello Unicode world!"
```

4) Use follwing meta tag in  section of your base template:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: How can i change my existing databases to support UTF-8. is it enough to add # -*- coding: utf-8 -* in settings.py or in every python file?

Comment: you should add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in every file where you use unicode symbols. this link http://www.devcha.com/2008/03/convert-existing-mysql-database-from.html can help you with converting your existing database tables, but "always do backups"