# UnicodeEncodeError raised when 'createsuperuser' is called

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, character-encoding

I am trying to deploy my Django application (2.1.5 with Python 3.6.6) on my server with a PostGreSQL database.
I did a 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' as usual and then I can't create a super user with the command 'createsuperuser':

```
[alex@web574 myproject]$ python3.6 manage.py createsuperuser
Nom d'utilisateur (leave blank to use 'alex'): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 60, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 139, in handle
    input_value = self.get_input_data(field, message)
  File "/home/alex/webapps/global_hse_project/lib/python3.6/Django-2.1.5-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 194, in get_input_data
    raw_value = input(message)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I found on Google to add:

```
# -*- Coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of the file but it doesn't work, same result with the variable DEFAULT_CHARSET (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_CHARSET).
My PostGreSQL database are asking for utf-8 encoding.

Comment: This probably has to do with the encoding used by your terminal and / or Python. Search for "UnicodeEncodeError terminal" and see if anything there helps you.

Comment: In your shell, try setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable before running the `createsuperuser` command. So run: `export PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"; python3.6 manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: @WillKeeling, you right ! It was due to the env var PYTHONIOENCODING.

Comment: @Rekoc - great, will add an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may be caused by the fact that encoding used for the stdin does not support the characters being typed in at the `input()` prompt.

You can try explicitly setting the encoding to `UTF-8` using the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable before you run the `createsuperuser` command:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"; python3.6 manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the same problem as here:
[previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061842/how-to-set-django-and-mysql-work-with-utf-8)
You have to add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the start of each file to include the right encoding